# Most efficient way of creating a TextureManager in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm working on a small SDL2 example, and i'm thinking about creating a TextureManager. I have a small abstraction, a class that handles IMG_LoadTexture and SDL_RenderCopy. During the constructor, i run IMG_LoadTexture and store the SDL_Texture* on a member variable. After that, if the render() method is called, i run SDL_RenderCopy. I want those abstracted Texture objects to live inside a TextureManager, which has the renderer instance and handle all rendering.

What's the best approach? A vector, with all Texture instances? How can this be more efficient? Is this a proper abstraction?

Comment: You are using SDL_Texture for sprites(2D); no manipulation?

Comment: Yes, i am. Following this tuts: https://github.com/Twinklebear/TwinklebearDev-Lessons/tree/master/Lesson0

Comment: I suggest you look at [SDL Tutorials](http://www.sdltutorials.com/).  I think you can find in the forums his [Texture Class](http://forums.gamedesigncenter.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=356&sid=9fc6eee95771f9e4b64c005bf9716244)

Comment: Unfortunately, they are SDL 1, not 2. :(

Comment: Yeah, but the basic idea/format for a texture manager is there.  Just fix the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The type of container that is most efficient relates to how often you add, delete, or access the elements, rather than the type of the elements.

vector is best if you access them a lot but don't make changes:  O(1) for random access, but up to O(N) for adding (likely less), O(N) for deletions if you care about ordering, O(1) otherwise.

list is good if you make a lot of insertions, but the insertions are all at the ends of the list:  O(N) for accesses and deletions, but O(1) to add to either end.

I could go on (deque, map), but I'd say it's dead certain that access is the most common needs, so vectors are the way to go.

I have to wonder if you're asking something else, though, since you add detail about SDL.  But your *question* is about what kind of abstraction will give you the most efficiency.  Is that the question you intended to ask?